# Capturing output from shell() function

Tags: r

I need to evoke some shell commands using R. I also need to capture output from that command (it is printed into R console). Unfortunately capture.output does not work.

```
> shell("test")
'test' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning message:
In shell("test") : 'test' execution failed with error code 1
```

I need to capture that part:

```
'test' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Does any of You know how to solve that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `intern = TRUE`:

```
out <- shell("test", intern = TRUE)
out
#[1] "'test' is not recognized as an internal or external command,"
#[2] "operable program or batch file."                             
#attr(,"status")
#[1] 1
```

Comment: It almost works for me. Problem is I want to have both. Console output (exactly the same) and output in a variable. All because I want to throw errors additional to exact shell error, not instead of it.

Comment: You can always paste the output together and then also cat it right? That would solve it. `cat(paste(out, collapse=' '))`

Comment: It screws formating a bit but its not  so bad, thanks.